# bollean value as true not saved in ajax

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Rails 3.2.8:

I have these parameters sent in an ajax request:

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"√", "comment"=>{"comment"=>"blah blah", "is_sensitive"=>"1"}
```

In the code I have:

```
@comment = Comment.new(params[:comment])
```

The comment is saved, but is_sensitive remains false, even-though it got the "1" value to the server. Why?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like `Comment` contains protection from [mass-assignment](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/mass-assignment-rails-and-you--net-31695). Check `attr_protected` and `attr_accessible` helpers inside your model.